# Java não Finaliza arquivo txt, gera txt mais de 100MB

Tags: txt

Meu arquivo de saída, não por qual motivo, agora não finaliza, se deixar rodando cria arquivo de texto com mais de **1GB**, só para se eu encerrar o processo no gerenciador de tarefas, no link acima esta o código do meu aplicativo, abertura do arquivo e fechamento, mas estar em **loop**, não consigo encontrar o problema.

Para maior entendimento ver: [Java - Ler arquivo e Gravar saida em .txt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276015/java-ler-arquivo-e-gravar-saida-em-txt)

Answer (score 0):

Note que na resposta da outra pergunta o trecho que grava as informações tem um comentário "//omitido" isso porque era para juntar com o seu código. Naquele trecho se você remover o comando para ler nova linha ele não vai seguir no arquivo e vai ficar em loop.